# Why Salesforce REST API List View Describe Method returns extra values in columns list?

Tags: rest-api, rest, list, list-view, filters

When I try to execute this request 
GET /vXX.X/sobjects/{sobjectType}/listviews/{queryLocator}/describe 
which is described in documentation
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_listviewdescribe.htm
I see that some extra fields are returned always in columns section disregarding if those fields are actually selected for display or not.

These fields are SystemModstamp LastModifiedDate RecordTypeId Id  CreatedDate

It is not possible to select SystemModstamp Id fields.
It is possible to select fields   LastModifiedDate RecordTypeId CreatedDate to be displayed on List View but there is no way to detect whether these fields are displayed or not since they are always returned even if they are not configured to display.

Does anyone know a solution or workaround for this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to check by `hidden` boolean field.